# Network Profile is not updated when I sign in to a new site on SE

Tags: support, profile-page, serverfault

**Expected behavior:**
When you have an account change, let's say you sign in to a new SE site, the Network Profile should immediately add such a forum to your list of the forums to show that you belong to that new forum.

**What happened:**
[My question](https://serverfault.com/questions/280780/where-are-the-radius-log-events-logged) was migrated to ServerFault and after that I immediately signed in to that new site - and now on my account there is a question and appropriate badges etc. On my Network Profile there still did not appear any new forum link under the accounts tab.

**What was wrong / What is the actual question?**
On Network Profile there should be visible all my sites where I am in, but the newest - ServerFault - is missing. I see this as a bug, because my profile keeps out of date of my current status on SE.

**btw.** This is my first question on meta ServerFault - this should be added on the list also soon :) Also, this might be due to slow aggregation, but then: you could enhance it then.

Comment: Give it a day to catch up.

Comment: Actually what helped finally was to disassociate and associate one account so that it contained on its list all the accounts I have and then using "Copy -- to all Stack Exchange accounts" to give the same list to every other account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dissociate all of your accounts, and then reassociate them.  I had this happen recently with Web Applications, and I found that reassociating them a few at a time rather than all the accounts at once worked.  (All this available from your `"Accounts"` tab halfway down the page in your profile)

Comment: You mean that button saying: `Copy Server Fault profile to all Stack Exchange accounts` ?

Comment: @Mikko do the `Clear All Associations` first.  Then click `Associate with other sites`.  It took me a couple of tries of clearing and associating just now, so it may not go the first time.

Comment: I cleared and re-associated the StackOverflow account and then the data appeared to the Network Profile. Thanks for tips @jonsca

Comment: @Mikko no problem, glad it worked for ya

Comment: hmm.. quite confusing: I lost the connection to SF after some surfing and now the only association after repeating this steps is to the SO itself only.

Comment: Dissociate everything, reassociate it (make sure all of them are on the list), then go to each site and make sure it recognizes you.  It may come up with the message "You are associated with N other Stack Exchange accounts" like it did the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it just hasn't caught up yet, I do not see ServerFault listed under accounts for you. Are you sure you associated your accounts properly?